# Verifying a user via SMS, E-mail or randomized scrambled images

Tags: email, sms, verification

I've tried searching for an answer, but can't find what I'm looking for.

There are a few known ways to avoid bots and fake accounts in your app:

1. SMS verification (6 digit PIN with confirmation)
2. e-mail confirmation (click on a link in the e-mail received)
3. Randomized blurry or scrambled pictures of text (type the same information in a textfield)
4. Pay small amount and refund (usually 1 cent)

**So what is the best way to verify that users are real people and not overpriced?**

Some companies charge 7 cents per successful sms, which is still quite a lot for a free app. Does anyone know any cheaper way or better method to verify a users identity? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Most wireless providers operate an email-to-SMS gateway, that you can use to send a message originating as an email, which will terminate as an SMS message.  For example, to send an email-to-SMS message to a Verizon Wireless user, you would email the message to xxxxxxxxxx@vtext.com (where xxxxxxxxxx is the phone number of the user).  See http://martinfitzpatrick.name/list-of-email-to-sms-gateways/ for a list of other providers.  Most, if not all, of these providers to not charge for sending through these gateways (although charges for receiving text messages may apply to the recipient).

BTW, the 'scrambled images' that you are referring to are called "captcha's".  See http://www.captcha.net/